# SQL UPPER only specific word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know how I can change only a word in the varchar field in my database?  They are formatted like "Cheese", "cheese", "CheesE".  I want to change to them all to CHEESE, but I have other text in those fields as well.  I was wondering if their was a way to single that word out and make it uppper.

Something like

```
update table
set field = Upper(cheese)+rest of field
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
update table
set field = replace(field, 'cheese', 'CHEESE')
```

### [SQLFIddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15729)

Comment: Though this will also lead to `cheesecake` becoming `CHEESEcake`

Comment: OP want to replace this specific word and not words that contain that word too.

Comment: the field says "cheEse of all flavors" not just "cheEse"

Comment: I just tested it.  It leaves the rest of my text alone!  Great!

Comment: @juergend - Your answer replaces the substring "cheese" not the word "cheese" though. May be a pedantic distinction in this case as I can't think of many words that contain the substring `cheese` though. But for other strings it would make a difference. e.g. `replace(field, 'rat', 'RAT')` would lead to words like `sepaRATe`

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I can see the diference between substring and word.
It is possible to do this kind of 'word-centric' transformation using XML as a proxy format.

Try this...

```
DECLARE @pattern nvarchar(max) = 'cheese'

SELECT 
    converted =
        cast('<a><i>' + REPLACE(field, ' ', '</i><i>') + '</i></a>' as xml)
            .query(
                'for $x in /a/i return
                    if (not( ($x) is (/a/i[last()])[1] )) then
                        if (data($x) = sql:variable("@pattern")) then
                            concat(upper-case($x), "")
                        else
                            concat($x, "")
                    else
                        if (data($x) = sql:variable("@pattern")) then
                            string(upper-case($x))
                        else
                            string(data($x))')
            .value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM table
```

I'm sure that it's possible to do it by parsing the expression char-by-char but I wanted to try it with XML :)